# In IE new window is opening instead of new tab in selenium web driver manager

Tags: java, selenium

We have developed selenium scripts for automation testing of our web application, to open few child links in a new tab. While executing these scripts in Internet Explorer browser, we observe that they are opening in a new window instead of new tab.

But these selenium scripts are working fine while testing with Google chrome and Microsoft Edge browsers. Are we missing any setting to be done in Internet Explorer browser. Can you help us to resolve this issue?

Comment: paste your code. Its difficult to help we can't see what was done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As requested, given below is the code snippet:
  Input.clickOn(settingsPage, cCLICK);
When we execute the above script, the expected web page does not open in a new tab. And the following is the implementation of clickOn method:
   waitUntilElementClickable(click_Locator);
    try {
         Input.getDriver().findElement(click_Locator).click();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) Input.getDriver();
         executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Input.getDriver().findElement(click_Locator));

Answer (score 0):

In C#. Alternatively you could use the SendKeys CTRL+T , to open a new tab, by using the page body as a locator reference:

Instead of `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open()")` //will open a new window in InternetExplorer

I use `driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");` //will open a new tab in InternetExplorer

Comment: As suggested, we have modified as follows: Input.getDriver().findElement(settingsPage).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t"); 
When we execute the above script in Internet Explorer browser, it does not work as expected and the following Java debug messages are displayed:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element cannot be interacted with via the keyboard because it is not focusable
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-7', revision: 'de8579b6d5'
  java.version: '1.8.0_281'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver